# Should I store Enum ID/values in the database or a C# enumeration?

Tags: c#, database, enums, constants

Say my database tables have columns like `UserType`, `SalesType`, etc.

Should I have database tables with `UserTypeID`, `userTypeName` or should I just create a C# enumeration?

Comment: Similar question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492096/persisting-data-suited-for-enums/

Answer (score 13):

What's wrong with both? If value's are user-defined or changing, definitely `enum` will not be suitable.

If values are strictly non-changing (such as gender), you can have them as `enums` for ease of reference in the application and also in the DB as separate table to enforce foreign keys and as a reference.

Answer (score 8):

It depends. I listed a few pros and cons for each approach below. In general, I strongly prefer enums if the application needs to use a value to make decisions. As Mehdrad mentioned, you can use both approaches but it requires extra effort to keep the lists in sync.

Lookup tables:

- Referential integrity can be enforced
  through foreign keys
- Easy to add or remove existing values
- Table can be extended to add additional fields (active flag, etc.)
- Requires additional class if using business objects
- Easy to use value and description in reports

Enum:

- Check constraint can enforce data integrity
- Best choice if code needs to use value for branching (e.g. x == SalesType.Web vs. x == "WEB")
- Requires software release to change values
- Cannot display description in SQL queries (without CASE)
- Enum may not be appropriate for display in UI (there are workarounds)

Answer (score 0):

If the list is stable enough to use an enum, then I would use an enum in your code plus a table in the database (make it a foreign key for data consistency).

Answer (score 0):

In my projects, I use my application [dbscript](http://devio.wordpress.com/category/dbscript/) to generate C# consts from database, so code always matches db values.

Of course, you only need to have C# enums if your code does something specific depending on the value of the Type field.