# Should I ever use Enums as discriminators?

Tags: .net, oop, enums

When do Enumerations break down?

---

To support a new feature in an existing system, I was just considering implementing some form of discriminator to an entity table in my database schema.

In wanting to begin by doing the least thing that will work I first of all decided on an integer column and a C# enum at the business entity layer for the sake of readability. This would provide the poor-man's polymorphism that may eventually grow into an actual polymorphism and perhaps towards a Strategy pattern.

I decided to consult the blogosphere as I've never been entirely comfortable with using enums - I wondered, should I skip the enum and go straight for a struct or a class?:

First of all I found an assertion that '[Enums are Evil](http://devpinoy.org/blogs/cruizer/archive/2007/09/12/enums-are-evil.aspx)', but I felt this was an over-generalization which does not directly address my use-case.

If I do go for an enum then there's a good discussion of how I can [extend my mileage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008090/c-enum-values) by adding extra metadata to my enum.

Next, I came across Jimmy Bogard's discussions of [Enumeration Classes](http://www.lostechies.com/blogs/jimmy_bogard/archive/2008/08/12/enumeration-classes.aspx) and further discussed in '[Strategies and discriminators in NHibernate](http://www.lostechies.com/blogs/jimmy_bogard/archive/2008/08/26/strategies-and-discriminators-in-nhibernate.aspx)'

Should I skip the enums and go straight for Enumeration Classes? Or does anyone have any other suggestions for how to add a simple entity discriminator to my domain model.

**Update:**

I'd also add that both NHibernate and LINQ to SQL (and probably all other ORM-related data-access methods) make the use of enums very enticing as they [let you map a discriminator column](http://www.davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2007/10/28/LINQToSQLEnumSupportExampleDiscriminatorColumnInheritanceMapping.aspx) transparently in the mapping.

Would it be as easy to map an Enumeration Class?

**Related questions:**

- [/492096/persisting-data-suited-for-enums](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492096/persisting-data-suited-for-enums)
- [/746812/best-practices-for-using-and-persisting-enums](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/746812/best-practices-for-using-and-persisting-enums)

---

Disclaimer:

Despite my careless use of the term entity (with a lower case 'e') I don't claim to be discussing DDD here...

Comment: Readers may like to note that if you do decide to use an enum then there is an interesting discussion on whether/how to persist the values in the DB here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/746812/best-practices-for-using-and-persisting-enums

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those Enumeration Classes look neat, I've often looked jealously at Java's enums.

I think the usual rules apply: do the Simplest Thing That Could Possibly Work. If you find yourself with more than one `switch` on the enum, then that's a smell, and time to consider the pattern you've found.

Otherwise, why burden yourself with something you don't need?

Answer (score 5):

Today enums are evil, tomorrow OOP might be evil and AOP will be fine.

Just use the right tool for the job.  Remember, **Keep It Simple**...

If the enum is just for the sake of telling the type of an object - don't bother, use it.

If it has some business logic in it, then it is probably another class.

Comment: The problem with starting simple is that if I use an Enum my 'foreign key' is an integer. If I later refactored to the disriminator being a full first-class entity (albeit just a lookup table) then I might wish that the foreign key had been a GUID (which happens to be the 'standard' we use for keys in our schema.

Comment: Then map Enum as a guid.  Just think if you really need it NOW. If not, just Keep It Simple.

Comment: OK, fine. But if, by that point, I have some legacy of data then I have some pretty non-trivial database refactoring to do.

Comment: What if you wont? You will maintain more complex solution during the application lifetime. So introduce complexity if you KNOW it is needed.

Comment: Ironically I decided to deviate from the 'standard' because this is a lookup not an entity so it seemed to make more sense having an integer PK instead of a GUID (which the DBAs hate anyway). I feel a whole new question coming on regarding the modelling of lookups vs entities... :-)